# Export GIS data to interactive report

Tags: software-recommendations, reports

I'm looking into the possibility of creating an all-in-one portable report derived from data compiled in GIS. This would contain a campus map with point data which, when clicked, would take the user to the relevant entry in a table and ideally have an option to open an image.

A software package might be an option. I'm aware of TerraGo (far too expensive) and InstantAtlas (a bit too expensive probably and uses ArcMap) - both of these offer more than I need.  I use QGIS on Linux, but can use Windows 7.  Some of the related answers on StackExchange are ArcMap-based & my future is not with this.

I wondered about HTML/web tech. Not sure if this can be done as a single file or some other unbreakable setup. Webmapping etc is not an option and I can't see sending the data with a free GIS viewer working, as it needs to be reasonably end user proof.

Can anyone advise any packages to look at, or how (conceptually- I can learn the nuts & bolts) I might achieve this with any of the options above, or anything else?

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating a web map.

There are two useful plugins available for QGIS via the Plugin repository, these are QGIS Cloud and QGIS Leaflet maps.

If you want a basic interactive viewer where an end user can pan around, zoom in and out and basic interact with vector data then you should consider web mapping.

A generated url is produced for your web map, you could put this into your report.

Comment: Not tried webmapping (i) I've not done anything in this field so would be major learning curve for me (but not against that). (ii)  the client saw that as too complicated (in terms of delivering to their clients, security of sensitive info and stuff at their end as they are only a small firm & this is low profit-margin work for them - they get their main profit from subsequent site maintenance work). 

It may be the way forward, but is a lot more involved than delivering an active PDF or other single file. If I knew I could deliver, I would try & make the case to. Will look at those plugins.

Comment: QGIS2leaf is not working for me- same problem as https://github.com/Geolicious/qgis2leaf/issues/179

Comment: Here's a link to a quickstart guide for QGIS Cloud just in case you might consider going down that route: https://qgiscloud.com/pages/quickstart

Comment: Also, check out http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/ for step-by-step tutorials from the most basic intro to QGIS to advanced analysis. Great web tutorials and come with free data for practice.